# Perpendicular Current Carrying Wires Forces?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image: Diagram]

Hi guys, I'm having trouble understanding the effect of sides BA and CD on the straight wire. With an amperian loop around the straight wire, the magnetic field on BA and CD is into the page, and then you have a leftward force on BA and a rightward force on CD.

[image]

Is it as simple as 'the sides are perpendicular and do not contribute any force'?

Thanks

Comment: yes,its as simple as that

Comment: @LandosAdam Why? Was my explanation correct?

Comment: $\vec B$ is in the same direction for each, but the direction of the current is reversed. Since $\vec B \times I d(-\vec l)$ = $\vec B \times I (-d\vec l) = -\vec B \times I d\vec l$, the force is equal in magnitude but opposite in direction.